# Subspaces and Dimension of sum of two subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

A simple question.i am in the initial phase of learning linear algebra. Need your help.

I have made it through my own understanding. Wanted to know if i am thinking right.

Lets take the subspace {(a,b,c,d,e,0,0,0,0,0,0) $ \forall $ a,b,c,d,e $ \in $ R} . What i wanted to know is whether we can regard this subspace as the vector space $ R^5 $ ??? as we can get any vector in $ R^5 $ using this subspace as all the other coordinates in the remaining dimensions are "0"...so, we can say that :

{(a,b,c,d,e,0,0,0,0,0,0) $ \forall $ a,b,c,d,e $ \in $ R} is a subspace of $ R^{11} $ or it is the vector space $ R^5 $ ....we can say either way right??

as for another example lets take the subspace {(a,b,1) $ \forall $ a,b $ \in $ R}. Here we can say that it is subspace of $ R^3 $ but not the vector space $ R^2 $ as the third coordinate is "1" here and not "0"..had it been "0" we could have said it is subspace of $ R^3 $ or it is the vector space $R^2$..am i thinking it the right way???

my second doubt is :

we know dim(U1+U2) = dim(U1)+dim(U2)-dim(U1 $\cap$ U2)  (here dim denotes dimension)

i have gone through the proof and its fine.What i also thought of it is as follows :

Let U1 = {(a,b,c,0,0,0) $\forall$ a,b,c $\in$ R}

let U2 = {(0,0,d,e,f,g) $\forall$ d,e,f,g $\in$ R}

Now,when we will take the dimension of U1+U2, we will get the 3rd coordinate of the vector space (U1+U2) as common from both the subspaces, thus all we have to do is write the dimension as :

dim(U1+U2) = 3+4-1 = 6. I guess i am right on this one.If not, kindly point out my mistake.

Besides, as i mentioned in my first doubt, can we write here U1 is the subspace of $R^6$ or it is the vector space $R^3$?? Similarly U2 is the subspace of $R^6$ or it is the vector space $R^4$??? In case of U2, the coordinates are any real number at 3rd,4th,5th and 6th place..if i am thinking right in my first doubt,can we here also say that U2 is the vector space $R^4$?? coz what i think where the coordinates are real (other than "0" ofcourse)   the place where the coordinates are placed should not bother us ...

Thanks for your patience...one final question..

If whatever i have said upto now is right, then lets take the subspace :

{(0,a,0,0,b,0,0,0,c) $\forall$ a,b,c $\in$ R}

My question is the same.Can we say it is a subspace of $R^9$ or that it is the vector space $R^3$ ???

So, these are the things i wanna clear out. i know its simple ones. I have just started learning linear algebra. and the way i am thinking is not explained in the book. So, needed help from you guys.Thanks for taking time to read and Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: besides, i know the proof of the dimension of sum of two subspaces using their basis. I am totally cool with it. Just wanted to clarify the above doubts. I thought about it myself and wanted to know if i am going right....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done the sum dimension just right.

As for $U_2$, for example, you can easily say that $U_2$ is *isomorphic to* (roughly, "behaves the same as") $\Bbb R^4$. You should be cautious, though, about saying that it *is* $\Bbb R^4$, since there are many subspaces of $\Bbb R^6$ isomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$.

Only one thing is well and truly incorrect: $\{(a,b,1):a,b\in\Bbb R\}$ is not a linear subspace of $\Bbb R^3,$ as (for one thing) it isn't closed under vector addition.

Comment: Thanks for your help... and yes u are right on that one...but one doubt...i guess its closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication but the vector {(0,0,0)} is not contained in it,thats why it is not a subspace of $ R^3 $...am i wrong in it??

Comment: It is *not* closed under vector addition, nor under scalar multiplication, nor does any element have an additive inverse, nor does it contain the identity. All these are reasons why it isn't a subspace.

Comment: or i guess we can say that its not a linear subspace coz of two reasons : {(0,0,0)} is not there in it and besides, through closed under vector addition we must also get {(0,0,0)} through addition of some vectors in the subspace. as the two conditions are not satisfied, its not a vector subspace of $R^3$. but however, its closed under scalar multiplication as we can get all the points including {(0,0,0)} when the scalar is 0. am i right?? let me know if u get time..thanks...

Comment: The fact that $(0,0,0)$ isn't in there is enough to show us that it isn't closed under scalar multiplication. Actually, for any scalar $c\ne1$ and any $a,b$, we have $$c(a,b,1)=(ca,cb,c),$$ which is not of the correct form to be an element of the given set (since $c\ne1$), so the set isn't even *remotely* closed under scalar multiplication. Neither is it closed under vector addition, since $$(a,b,1)+(a',b',1)=(a+a',b+b',2)$$ is not of the appropriate form to be an element of the set (since $2\ne 1$).

Comment: cant we say that it is closed under scalar multiplication ??? coz we can take the scalar as "0" and thus will get the vector {(0,0,0)} as well. ...i guess i m thinking it wrong...

Comment: got u now!!! thanks a lot!!! :)))

Comment: Excellent! Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

$U:=\{(a,b,0)\mid a,b\in\Bbb R\}$ is a (linear) *subspace* of $\Bbb R^3$, that's right.
It is *not equal* to $\Bbb R^2$, because its elements are certain *triples* of real numbers, whereas the elements of $\Bbb R^2$ are *pairs* of real numbers.

However, $U$ has dimension $2$, and as such, is *isomorphic* to $\Bbb R^2$, in other words, they *can be identified* by the mapping $(a,b,0)\mapsto (a,b)$, which is a linear bijection (isomorphism) between $U$ and $\Bbb R^2$.

Also, $\{(a,b,1)\mid a,b\in\Bbb R\}$ is *not* a linear subspace of $\Bbb R^3$, because each linear subspace must contain the zero (now $(0,0,0)$). However, it is a 'shifted subspace', so called *affine subspace*.

The subspaces of the $3$ dimensional space are: the origin itself (0d), all the lines through the origin (1d), all the planes through the origin (2d), and the space itself (3d).

Comment: thanks for your feedback..will study about this more..And yes right on that one..{(a,b,1) $ \forall $ a,b $ \in $ R} is not a subspace of $ R^3 $... my mistake...